# PHP script to clear cache in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, caching, joomla

I created the following script and put it to cron job on server. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
include 'includes/defines.php';
include 'includes/framework.php';

$conf = JFactory::getConfig();

$options = array(
    'defaultgroup' => '',
    'storage'      => $conf->get('cache_handler', ''),
    'caching'      => true,
    'cachebase'    => $conf->get('cache_path', JPATH_SITE . '/cache')
);

$cache = JCache::getInstance('', $options);
$cache->clean('cachegroup');
```

Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: I nothing is work - the cache is not cleared. I assume that is a probnlem with Joomla-Framework.

Comment: Perhaps try asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.